# Employee Scheduling Software? Web/Browser Based

Tags: web-applications, scheduling, project-planning

Just wondering if any of you guys know of any web-based/browser-based employee scheduling software/tools?

Currently doing it all in Excel, but it just isnt intelligent enough... any product suggestions?

Needs to handle multiple employees time over weeks and months... to schedule in work short-term and long-term, allow me to see possible resourcing issues etc etc.

Its an easy question answer when you work only on projects, but at my agency we work on projects and day-to-day retainer type things that can come in at any time and are usually of the "drop everything and do this now" type.

If it were just projects, then any one of the online Project Management tools (GoPlan, Copper Project, MS Project) would suffice (but definately not Basecamp, I find this ok for very small projects and small teams, but anything larger and I think it falls down completely as a PM tool)

The only thing that came close to doing all that I wanted was Workschedule - http://www.workschedule.net/

Its browser based, low-cost and has a zillion options that really allowed me to plan resource levels for the agency. The only downside is it looks pretty awful, but I soon got over this.

Clarification: Must be general purpose i.e. not just for one industry

Comment: Um, if it's not just for the software industry, and it doesn't relate to writing programs, it doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Andykiteman it's been nearly 6 years that you asked this question. Have you found what you were looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My girlfriend's employer uses: http://www.hotschedules.com/ from what I have seen it seems to be pretty feature-complete...

Comment: HotSchedules looks great for restaurants, but I was hoping for something more general purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [@task](http://www.attask.com/) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a hosted  [employee scheduling software](http://orchestrateapp.com/employee-scheduling-software.html) app called Orchestrate.

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be an old post, but for anyone still interested, there is a new free service by Enigmai (http://www.enigmai.com)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.whentowork.com

Comment: The UI is a bit of a disaster IMHO

Comment: That site looks like it was made in FrontPage 98.

Answer (score 1):

[VIP Task Manager Pro](http://www.taskmanagementsoft.com/products/taskmanagerpro/)?

Solutions:
    * Employee Task Planning
    * Sales Process Management
    * To Do List Management
    * Project Management
    * Employee Time Planning
    * Schedule Management
    * Team Collaboration
    * Employee Task Tracking
    * Workflow Automation
    * Employee Time Tracking
    * Workgroup Productivity Management
    * Purchasing Process Management

> ...simultaneous access to the common
>   database through Local Network (LAN)
>   and Low Speed Networks (Internet, VPN)

"Assign Tasks to Employees"

Price: $399.90 $500.00(until March 31, 2009)

It looks like they have a Camtasia playback demo you could check out.

Comment: The UI is pretty dreadful IMHO

Answer (score 1):

We've been with [findmyshift.com](http://www.findmyshift.com/) for about a year now. Easiest site I could find at the time. Free for week to week use (we don't need to book to far ahead). Comes with text messaging and all that built in.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for [JustRosters.com](http://www.JustRosters.com)

edit: Just noticed they have a [30 day free trial on all plans](http://www.justrosters.com/pages/pricing)

Answer (score 1):

Was mentioned earlier but I'd also recommend **findmyshift.com** - simplest interface I've seen by far.

Answer (score 1):

My friend at his radiology company, and my other friend at his staffing company use a locally installable web browser based tool called OnSched from http://www.azazia.com.  He got one for free when he offered to write a testimonial.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for general purpose stuff.. suitable for different industries then Microsoft project plan software is the best choice, has wide range of project management solutions. It can be used in many industries like media, education, construction, oil and gas, finance etc. Refer to case studies of Microsoft [project management solutions](http://www.microsoft.com/project/en/us/customer-success.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Check this one: http://keeptempo.com, its tag approach seems to accommodate the extra flexibility you are looking for http://keeptempo.com/help/time-reporting/how-can-i-use-tags-to-organize-my-time/

Comment: This app is primarily focused on time tracking, to schedule staff effectively I need to be able to direct them and not just track their hours after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Here's mine:
http://quickrosters.com

Sourcecode is here:
http://rosters.rubyforge.org

And another good one:
http://justrosters.com

Answer (score -2):

I love WSS (Windows Sharepoint Services).  It's free and installs on W2K3 or W2K8 Server.  Very easy to use out of the box.  And easily customizable.  With Intelligantt you can publish your MS Project files there as well.  Then by plugging in Microsoft Office Sharepoint Designer you can built some custom workflows.

And of course the favorite integration with Microsoft Office Outlook is always a plus.  You can export your calendars and task lists.